# With the Orbeon Proxy Portlet is there a way to enable form selection via Inter Portlet Communication?

Tags: orbeon

The Orbeon Proxy Portlet allows [form selection via URL parameters](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Portal-~-Liferay-Proxy-Portlet-Guide#enabling-form-selection-via-url-parameters). It would be preferable if the parameters were not included in the URL. I thought I might be able to use a public render parameter as described in the [Liferay documentation](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication) but it looks like the proxy portlet isn't configured that way.

Looking at `OrbeonProxyPortlet.scala` I see this method is used to retrieve the URL parameters:

```
private def portalQuery(request: PortletRequest) =
    collectByErasedType[String](request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string")) map decodeSimpleQuery getOrElse Nil
```

Could this method be modified to combine that map with the map returned by  [`PorletRenderRequest.getParameterMap()`](http://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html#getParameterMap())  or [`PorletRenderRequest.getPublicParameterMap()`](http://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html#getPublicParameterMap())?

Or perhaps there could be another init-param like `enable-url-parameters`, for example, `enable-inter-portlet-parameters`?

This would also require the following configuration in the `portlet.xml`:

```
    <supported-public-render-parameter>orbeon-app</supported-public-render-parameter>
    <supported-public-render-parameter>orbeon-form</supported-public-render-parameter>
    <supported-public-render-parameter>orbeon-document</supported-public-render-parameter>
    <supported-public-render-parameter>orbeon-page</supported-public-render-parameter>
```

Comment: See my reply below. Feel free to enter an RFE or to submit a pull request on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, currently this is not implemented, and I don't think there is a way without modifying the code of `OrbeonProxyPortlet.scala`. But yes, it would make sense to make this work, and in fact the option was considered in issue [#1850](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1850).